# If $L^*$ or $L^+$ is empty, can L be an infinite language?

Tags: formal-languages, finite-sets

I have to prove or disprove the implications in these two situations

1. $L^* = \emptyset$ $\rightarrow$ $L$ is infinite
2. $L^+ = \emptyset$ $\rightarrow$ $L$ is infinite

Here are my thoughts.

1. I would say Kleene star operation (*) is union of

   $\qquad L^0 \cup L^1 \cup L^2 \cup \dots$

   and since $\_^0 = \{\epsilon\}$ (even $\emptyset^ 0 = \{\epsilon\}$), there is no language $L$ such that $L^* = \emptyset$.

   How to prove finiteness/infiniteness?
2. Only language $L$ where $L^+ = \emptyset$ is $\emptyset$ which is a finite language. But how to prove there is no other language that is inifinite and the argument is valid for it?

---

EDIT: will it help if I rewrite the implications $A \rightarrow B$ to $\neg B \rightarrow \neg A$ ?

1. $L$ is finite $\rightarrow$ $L^* \neq \emptyset$
2. $L$ is finite $\rightarrow$ $L^+ \neq \emptyset$

2) can be now interpreted as $\emptyset^+ = \{\epsilon\}$ and $\emptyset$ is a finite language. So the implication doesn't work.

Comment: If $L$ is infinite, then there is some $x \in L$. Since $L \subseteq L^*$ and $L \subseteq L^+$, you have $x \in L^*$ and $x \in L^+$, so both are nonempty. That $L$ is infinite isn't even relevant there, it's enough that $L$ is nonempty.

Comment: @G.Bach: Somehow I think the exercise got copied down wrongly...

Comment: "But how to prove there is no other language that is infinite and the argument is valid for it?" -- Pick any and see what happens.

Comment: @Raphael: I made it exactly the way the exercise was written in the paper.

Comment: Hint: $L^*$ is never empty.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: that's what I wrote, but how to prove the finity/infinity.

Comment: I think what Yuval hints at is a certain property of $\rightarrow$ in propositional logic. More concretely: What can be inferred from wrong assumptions?

Answer (score 3):

1) You need to take a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Remember that there is an *implication* to be proved true or false.

2) Consider the fact $L \subseteq L^{+}$ and apply it to the case $L^{+} = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to *prove or disprove*.

L* *always* contains the empty string and is therefore not empty. "L* is empty" is a false statement. Anything follows from a false statement. So yes, if L* is empty (which it cannot be) then L is infinite. L is also finite. And empty. And anything else, and all at the same time.

Let L be a language containing at least one string s. Then L+ contains s and is not empty. But if L is empty then L+ is empty. Therefore is L+ is empty, L is empty. And "L+ is empty" is possible, therefore "L+ is empty" implies L is empty, and it implies that L is not non-empty and definitely not infinite.